# Localhost wordpress admin issue. My dashboard does not show up

Tags: wordpress, dns, localhost

I need some help please!

I was in my Wordpress admin. By mistake, I changed the home page url and website url to the name of my domain by mistake. Before they were listed as http://localhost.

Now, I am not able to access the dashboard because the template I was working on shows up and does not let me click on anything because it directs me to the website.
I tried uninstalling wordpress and re-installing and it still does not work. I also tried writing the two lines on the wp-config.php file and it does not work.

I have been trying for 5 hours now and I can not get it to work.

Thank you. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Need to see the code in order to help you.  What name did you put in by mistake, what is in your wp-config? Please post it. What are you seeing when you're directed to the website? and what is the website?

Answer (score 1):

A lot of your URL's (including the login page) are controlled by the database.

That'll be what's redirecting you to the site online, and not your localhost.

You have a number of options here:

**Easiest:**
If you are good to start from scratch, then do so - and make sure you delete the database too. Otherwise, you're going to need to change the URLs in your database.

**Medium:**
Are you using phpMyAdmin? You can use the database search function to search for all references of your domina name, replacing it with localhost

**Most difficult** - or you can use these commands: http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/01/30/13-useful-wordpress-sql-queries-you-wish-you-knew-earlier/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Simply go to your phpmyadmin (or any other db manager) in order to execute the following sql code into your database:

```
UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = REPLACE (
option_value,
'http://old.com',
'http://localhost');

UPDATE wp_posts SET guid = REPLACE (
guid,
'http://old.com',
'http://localhost');

UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = REPLACE (
post_content ,
'http://old.com',
'http://localhost');

UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = REPLACE (
meta_value ,
'http://old.com',
'http://localhost');
```

Replace old.com with your domain.